# Est-ce que le mot « balado » est connu en France?

Tags: québec, internet

Au Québec, on utilise le mot « **balado** » pour les émissions audio sur l'internet. Examples : [Radio-Canada](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/ohdio/balados) et [le Journal de Montreal](https://www.journaldemontreal.com/2021/01/09/des-balados-plein-la-tete). Je sais qu'en France, l'emprunt anglais « **podcast** » est utilisé.  Examples : [RFI](https://www.rfi.fr/fr/podcasts/) et [le Monde](https://www.lemonde.fr/podcasts/).

Je me demande si les Français comprennent du tout le mot « balado » ou s'il y est complètement inconnu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le mot n'est employé en France que dans son dérivé : ***baladodiffusion***. Et je doute que le terme de *baladodiffusion* soit employé en dehors du cadre de l'enseignement des langues vivantes<sup>1</sup>. Apparu en France  vers le milieu de la première décennie de ce siècle, il me semble que désormais on lui préfère le terme de *podcasting*. La *baladodiffusion* ne diffuse pas, en France, de balados, mais des fichiers audio qu'on a tendance à appeler de plus en plus souvent des *podcasts*.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Ce [mémoire de Master 2](https://hal.univ-lorraine.fr/hal-01864794/document) consacré entièrement à la baladodiffusion ne contient pas une seule fois le terme *balado*.</sup>

Comment: *Balado* m'a fait penser à *baladeur* mais ce mot a disparu avec l'objet associé.

Comment: Franceterme recommande [_audio à la demande_](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=audio&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) pour contrer ce nom référant à un objet mort depuis belle lurette comportant un morceau de nom relié à une marque de commerce, là où l'Office a proposé [_balado_](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8869530) avec _fichier..._ pour distinguer le téléchargement de l'écoute en continu.

Comment: @jlliagre Effectivement le terme vient de baladeur, la baladodiffusion c'était l'utilisation de « [la diffusion par baladeur](https://www.education.gouv.fr/bo/2010/11/mene1006812c.htm). À une époque où la plupart des élèves en possédaient. Maintenant ils sont des smartphones avec connexion à internet, et internet est aussi rentrer dans les salles de classe (toutes, alors qu'il y a 15 ans ce n'était pas le cas).

Comment: @escarlateadamantine « Audio à la demande » n'est pas de tout utilisé dans le contexte scolaire (celui dont je parle), d'ailleurs « à la demande » ne correspondrait pas à l'usage qui en fait.  Et on trouve encore à la vente des « valises de baladodiffusion » contenant des baladeurs MP4 destinés au travail dans le cadre de la salle de classe (pas de pub...).

Answer (score 2):

C'est la première fois que je rencontre ce mot donc je dirais *complètement inconnu*.